# How to level up characters in D&D 5th edition?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-advancement

I'm a new dungeon master, and I'm looking to find out how to level up my players characters to level 2 after they defeated a few monsters. How would I go about doing this? I have no experience in the matter and am really only dungeon mastering my first game I have ever played because I have the time on my hands for research and love story building.

Comment: Thanks for asking! I've linked this to an existing question that matches this, where the answers should help you. (This kind of link helps keep all our answers for the same essential question in one place, and duplicates like this one help other searchers find the canonical question & answers. So thank you for asking.)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE.  There are a variety of "new DM" questions and answers that we hope you will find useful as you and your group play the game.